# tcolorbox: before upper and before lower causing alignment problems of content (itemize)

Tags: tcolorbox, alignment

## Problem

I am trying to typeset a [`tcolorbox`](https://ctan.org/pkg/tcolorbox?lang=en) ([documentation](https://texdoc.org/serve/tcolorbox/0)) called `solutionbox` which has two distinct parts: the `upper` section is for the solution, and the `lower` section is for the explanation.

I've defined a separate `sectionbox` (it's an inline `\tcbox{}` environment) which is used by the section titles of each respective section of my `solutionbox`.

I'm adding these titles using the `before upper*` and `before lower*` options for `solutionbox`.

This works perfectly, but I need to manually adjust the text alignment myself. Is there any way to do this better, preferrably so that subsequent lines of text are aligned correctly and environments like `itemize` and others don't end up overflowing to the left?

## MWE

```latex
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{article}

% Layout
\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{calc}

% Colour
\usepackage[dvipsnames, cmyk]{xcolor}

% Customising lists
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setitemize{noitemsep,topsep=0pt,parsep=4pt,partopsep=0pt,leftmargin=*}

% tcolorbox
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{%
    skins
}

%% Custom tcolorboxes
\NewTCBox
    {\sectionbox}
    { O{Violet} !O{} }  % 1: colour, 2: extra options
    {
        on line,
        arc=7pt,
        colback=#1!2.5!white,
        colframe=#1!90!black,
        colupper=#1,
        boxrule=1pt,
        boxsep=0pt,
        left=6.5pt,
        right=3pt,
        top=3pt,
        bottom=3pt,
        before upper={\rule[-2.5pt]{0pt}{10pt}},
        #2
    }

%%% Custom lengths   ---   This is the annoying finnicky part
\newlength{\widthofexplanation}
\settowidth{\widthofexplanation}{\widthof{\sectionbox{\textbf{Explanation:}}}}
\addtolength{\widthofexplanation}{5mm}

\newlength{\setbackwidthofexplanation}
\setlength{\setbackwidthofexplanation}{\widthofexplanation}
\addtolength{\setbackwidthofexplanation}{1mm}

\NewTColorBox
    {solutionbox}
    { O{Solution:} O{Violet} !O{} }  % 1: before title declaration, 2: colour, 3: extra options
    {
        enhanced,
        detach title,
        coltitle=#2,
        colframe=#2,
        colback=white,
        before upper={%
            \hspace{-\setbackwidthofexplanation}\makebox[\widthofexplanation][b]{\sectionbox{\textbf{#1}}}~\parindent15pt\noindent
        },
        before lower={%
            \hspace{-\setbackwidthofexplanation}\makebox[\widthofexplanation][b]{\sectionbox{\textbf{Explanation:}}}~\parindent15pt\noindent
        },
        left=\widthofexplanation,
        #3
    }

\title{\TeX{}.SE MWE}
\author{BrightBulb123}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section{Introduction}

\begin{enumerate}
    \item   Example question (the first one)
            \begin{solutionbox}
                \( x = math \)
            \end{solutionbox}
    \item   Example question (the second one)
            \begin{solutionbox}
                Written solution instead of math.
                %
                \tcblower
                %
                Here's a nice explanation for it. Enough to at least flow over to the next line. \\
                Here's another line for good measure :)
            \end{solutionbox}
    \item   Example question
            \begin{solutionbox}
                \( x = \frac{ -b \pm \sqrt{ b^2 - 4ac } }{ 2a } \) \\
                \( y = x^3 \)
                %
                \tcblower
                %
                \begin{itemize}
                    \item[\textbf{Sol. for \( x \):}] Blah blah blah.
                    \item[\textbf{Sol. for \( y \):}] More blah blah blah.
                \end{itemize}
            \end{solutionbox}
    
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

## Images

[image: Image of the output of the above MWE code; this is what the unfixed output is.]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In full example below, it's configured that a `\sectionbox` is inserted at the beginning of first paragraphs of both upper and lower parts of `solutionbox`. Non-default `\parshape` settings which will be set by list environments are taken into consideration.

Snippet

```tex
        before upper={%
          \AddToHookNext{para/begin}{%
            \llap{%
              \sectionbox{\textbf{#1}}%
              % \parshapeindent1 is the indent of first line
              \hskip\dimexpr\parshapeindent1+5pt\relax
            }%
          }%
        },
```

- `\AddToHookNext{<hook>}{<code>}` appends `<code>` to the next use of `<hook>` and the next use only. It's documented in one of LaTeX2e manuals, `texdoc lthooks-doc`.
- Hook `para/begin` is documented in one of LaTeX2e manuals, `texdoc ltpara-doc`.
- eTeX primitive `\parshapeindent` is documented in *The e-TeX manual* (`texdoc etex`).

Full example.

Note that `itemize` is replaced with `description`. Using variable label width in `itemize` may not be a good idea.

```tex
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{article}

% Layout
\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{calc}

% Colour
\usepackage[dvipsnames, cmyk]{xcolor}

% Customising lists
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist[itemize]{noitemsep,topsep=0pt,parsep=4pt,partopsep=0pt,leftmargin=*}
\setlist[description]{noitemsep,topsep=0pt,parsep=4pt,partopsep=0pt}

% tcolorbox
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{%
    skins
}

%% Custom tcolorboxes
\NewTCBox
    {\sectionbox}
    { O{Violet} !O{} }  % 1: colour, 2: extra options
    {
        on line,
        arc=7pt,
        colback=#1!2.5!white,
        colframe=#1!90!black,
        colupper=#1,
        boxrule=1pt,
        boxsep=0pt,
        left=6.5pt,
        right=3pt,
        top=3pt,
        bottom=3pt,
        before upper={\rule[-2.5pt]{0pt}{10pt}},
        #2
    }

%%% Custom lengths   ---   This is the annoying finnicky part
\newlength{\widthofexplanation}
\settowidth{\widthofexplanation}{\widthof{\sectionbox{\textbf{Explanation:}}}}
\addtolength{\widthofexplanation}{5mm}

\newlength{\setbackwidthofexplanation}
\setlength{\setbackwidthofexplanation}{\widthofexplanation}
\addtolength{\setbackwidthofexplanation}{1mm}

\NewTColorBox
    {solutionbox}
    { O{Solution:} O{Violet} !O{} }  % 1: before title declaration, 2: colour, 3: extra options
    {
        enhanced,
        detach title,
        coltitle=#2,
        colframe=#2,
        leftupper=\widthofexplanation,
        leftlower=\widthofexplanation,
        colback=white,
        before upper={%
          \AddToHookNext{para/begin}{%
            \llap{%
              \sectionbox{\textbf{#1}}%
              % \parshapeindent1 is the indent of first line
              \hskip\dimexpr\parshapeindent1+5pt\relax
            }%
          }%
        },
        before lower={%
          \AddToHookNext{para/begin}{%
            \llap{%
              \sectionbox{\textbf{Explanation:}}%
              \hskip\dimexpr\parshapeindent1+5pt\relax
            }%
          }%
        },
        #3
    }

\title{\TeX{}.SE MWE}
\author{BrightBulb123}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section{Introduction}

\begin{enumerate}
    \item   Example question (the first one)
            \begin{solutionbox}
                \( x = math \)
            \end{solutionbox}
    \item   Example question (the second one)
            \begin{solutionbox}
                Written solution instead of math.
                %
                \tcblower
                %
                Here's a nice explanation for it. Enough to at least flow over to the next line. \\
                Here's another line for good measure :)
            \end{solutionbox}
    \item   Example question
            \begin{solutionbox}
                \( x = \frac{ -b \pm \sqrt{ b^2 - 4ac } }{ 2a } \) \\
                \( y = x^3 \)
                %
                \tcblower
                %
                \begin{description}
                    \item[\textbf{Sol. for \( x \):}] Blah blah blah.
                    \item[\textbf{Sol. for \( y \):}] More blah blah blah.
                \end{description}
            \end{solutionbox}
    \item   More test
            \begin{solutionbox}
                \begin{itemize}
                    \item foo
                    \item bar
                \end{itemize}
                %
                \tcblower
                %
                \begin{description}
                    \item[\textbf{Sol. for \( x \):}] Blah blah blah.
                    \item[\textbf{Sol. for \( y \):}] More blah blah blah.
                \end{description}
            \end{solutionbox}
    
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure I understood the question.

To place a list next to the text, I suggest a `minipage`.

Note: It seems to me that the environment `description` better matches what you want. I use `\setlist`, `\setitemize` is depreciated.

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}%<<-- for the test
% Layout
\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{calc}

% Colour
\usepackage[dvipsnames, cmyk]{xcolor}

% Customising lists
\usepackage{enumitem}
%\setitemize{noitemsep,topsep=0pt,parsep=4pt,partopsep=0pt,leftmargin=*}
\setlist[description]{
noitemsep,
topsep=0pt,
parsep=4pt,
partopsep=0pt,
% leftmargin=*
}

% tcolorbox
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{%
skins
}

%% Custom tcolorboxes
\NewTCBox
{\sectionbox}
{ O{Violet} !O{} }  % 1: colour, 2: extra options
{
    on line,
    arc=7pt,
    colback=#1!2.5!white,
    colframe=#1!90!black,
    colupper=#1,
    boxrule=1pt,
    boxsep=0pt,
    left=6.5pt,
    right=3pt,
    top=3pt,
    bottom=3pt,
    before upper={\rule[-2.5pt]{0pt}{10pt}},
    #2
}

%%% Custom lengths   ---   This is the annoying finnicky part
\newlength{\widthofexplanation}
\settowidth{\widthofexplanation}{\widthof{\sectionbox{\textbf{Explanation:}}}}
\addtolength{\widthofexplanation}{5mm}

\newlength{\setbackwidthofexplanation}
\setlength{\setbackwidthofexplanation}{\widthofexplanation}
\addtolength{\setbackwidthofexplanation}{1mm}

\NewTColorBox
{solutionbox}
{ O{Solution:} O{Violet} !O{} }  % 1: before title declaration, 2: colour, 3: extra options
{
    enhanced,
    detach title,
    coltitle=#2,
    colframe=#2,
    colback=white,
    before upper={%
        \hspace{-\setbackwidthofexplanation}\makebox[\widthofexplanation][b]{\sectionbox{\textbf{#1}}}~\parindent15pt\noindent
    },
    before lower={%
        \hspace{-\setbackwidthofexplanation}\makebox[\widthofexplanation][b]{\sectionbox{\textbf{Explanation:}}}~\parindent15pt\noindent
    },
    left=\widthofexplanation,
    #3
}

\title{\TeX{}.SE MWE}
\author{BrightBulb123}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section{Introduction}

\begin{enumerate}
\item   Example question (the first one)
        \begin{solutionbox}
            \( x = math \)
        \end{solutionbox}
\item   Example question (the second one)
        \begin{solutionbox}
            Written solution instead of math.
            %
            \tcblower
            %
            Here's a nice explanation for it. Enough to at least flow over to the next line. \\
            Here's another line for good measure :)
        \end{solutionbox}
\item   Example question
        \begin{solutionbox}
            \( x = \frac{ -b \pm \sqrt{ b^2 - 4ac } }{ 2a } \) \\
            \( y = x^3 \)
            %
            \tcblower
            %
            \begin{minipage}[t]{\linewidth}
                \begin{description}
                    \item[Sol. for \( x \):] \lipsum[1]
                    \item[Sol. for \( y \):] More blah blah blah.
                    \end{description}
        \end{minipage}%
        \end{solutionbox}

\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

EDIT: with `labelindent`. I added `\DrawEnumitemLabel` for section 3.2 Horizontal spacing of labels in the enumitem documentation.

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{article}

% Layout
\usepackage[margin=2cm,showframe]{geometry}

\usepackage{enumitem}
%\setitemize{noitemsep,topsep=0pt,parsep=4pt,partopsep=0pt,leftmargin=*}
\setlist[itemize]{
    noitemsep,
    topsep=0pt,
    parsep=4pt,
    partopsep=0pt,
    leftmargin=*,
    % labelindent=52pt,
    }
\usepackage{lipsum}
\newlength{\mylength}
\settowidth{\mylength}{Sol. for \( x \):}
\begin{document}
Without labelindent:
\begin{itemize}
    \DrawEnumitemLabel
    \item \lipsum[1]
    \item More blah blah blah.
\end{itemize}

\noindent\rule{\linewidth}{0.4pt}

With option in item

\begin{itemize}
    \DrawEnumitemLabel
    \item[Sol. for \( x \):] \lipsum[1]
    \item[Sol. for \( y \):] More blah blah blah.
    \end{itemize}

\noindent\rule{\linewidth}{0.4pt}

With \protect\verb|labelindent=\mylength|
\setlist[itemize]{
    noitemsep,
    topsep=0pt,
    parsep=4pt,
    partopsep=0pt,
    leftmargin=*,
    labelindent=52pt,
    }
\the\mylength

\begin{itemize}[left=\mylength]
    \DrawEnumitemLabel
    \item[Sol. for \( x \):] \lipsum[1]
    \item[Sol. for \( y \):] More blah blah blah.
    \end{itemize} 
\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this. It seems to do the job, but any ideas on why the `itemize` environment phases through the "Explanation:" subheading (even with the minipage)? \\ As for "understanding the question", I'm sorry if it was too vague. I wanted exactly what you offered: a way for my content to not flow into the section headings (*i.e.,* "Solution:" and "Explanation:"). Plus I wanted a way to make computing the indentation of the content a bit less painfully, because right now, if you look at multiline content, the second line sort of dips before the first line (they don't line up right).

Comment: With `labelindent`, I update my answer